# return execute reader result with close connection command behavior, order of excecution

Tags: c#, return, connection-close, command-behaviors

It's a very simple question..I want to know based on the code below..Is the connection closed and then return estatement will be executed or the return estatement will be executed without closing the connection?..because I set the `CommandBehavior` to close the connection, but I think the connection will not be close at all..Am I right?

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(_constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (reader.Read())
                return Convert.ToInt32(reader["persianDate"].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the associated Connection object is closed when the associated
>   DataReader object is closed.

since you are not closing data reader before return there is no affect using `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` but your `using` block will close the connection.

I would add `using` blocks for both `SqlCommand` and `Reader` as well

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(_constr))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader["persianDate"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be closed. Calling `Dispose` on `SqlConnection` calls `Close` implicitly and because you use `using` statement you are guaranteed that `Dispose` will be always called at the end of block.